# For a ring $R$, $x^2=x$ for all $x\in R$ implies...

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I am studying old GRE problems for a class and think I have a handle on this problem and am just looking for guidance and verification.  Here are the 5 choices:

A)  $x=-x$ for all $x\in R$.

B)  $R$ is commutative

C)  $xy+yx=0$ for all $x,y \in R$

D)  Both A and C

E)  A, B, and C

Since $R$ is a ring, take $x,y \in R$ and look at $(x+y)^2$. We know $x+y$ is in the ring.   Thus,

$$(x+y)^2=(x+y)(x+y)=x(x+y)+y(x+y)$$
$$=xx+xy+yx+yy=x+xy+yx+y=x+y$$

So this shows that $xy+yx=0$ so C is definitely true.   A would not be necessarily true, since $xy\in R$, we have by the implication, $$xy=-yx\neq -(xy)$$

Therefore, logically, it has to just be C, right?

Comment: Notice that $1=(-1)^2=-1$. Thus, $x=-x$. By C), $xy=yx$ also.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, (A) holds in fact. For any $x\in R$,

$$1+x=(1+x)^2=1+2x+x^2=1+2x+x$$

which implies $2x=0$, i.e. $x=-x$.

Then (C) still holds, you're correct about that. But use the fact that (A) holds to show that (B) holds as well.

Comment: See, it's little things like letting $y=1$ that i always struggle with.  That makes it so clear;

Answer (score 4):

(A) is true! Try the following:
\begin{align*}
x^2&=x\\
(-x)^2&=-x\\
(-x)^2&=x^2\\
&=x
\end{align*}
By lines (2) and (4), it is clear that (A) holds.

Have you given (B) any thought?

Comment: okay, so once A holds, then B is extended off of that, since $xy=-yx=yx$, right?  so all A B and C

Comment: That's exactly right!